# Create a nested query to input the result of outer query into the inner query in sql

Tags: sql, rdbms

I need to migrate values from one table to another table. However, the structure of the tables and columns are different.

```
Table1 has one to one relationship with table2

Table1 (Saiyan). (latest table)
Id (PK), name.
1        Vegeta

Table2 (SaiyanPower) (latest table)
Identifier(PK), ID(FK),value1,     value2,       value3
1               1      SuperSaiyan SuperSaiyan2 SuperSaiyanBlue

Old Tables:
Table1 has one to many relationship

Table1 (old table) (SaiyanDistribution)
ID(PK), name.
1       Vegeta

Table2 (Old table) SaiyanDistributionValues
Identifier (PK), ID (FK), Value
1                1        SuperSaiyan
2                1        SuperSaiyan2
3                1        SuperSaiyanBlue
```

I need to migrate values from one table to another. I am not sure how can I save the row of old table1 (SaiyanDistribution), fetch the id to fetch the rows of old table2 (SaiyanDistributionValue) and then add it to new table1 (Saiyan), new table2 (SaiyanPower).

Comment: Your new table structure is atrocious. Leave your old tables as is.

Comment: Not an option for me. I probably can use Cursor to do that right.

Comment: What are you wanting to do is a PIVOT. This is implemented differently depending on your RDBMS. Can you update your questions tag with your RDBMS (mysql, sql server, postgres, oracle, etc..) The appropriate expert here may be able to write that up for you then.

Comment: Do you always have 3 and only 3 values for each saiyan ?

Comment: Yes. Always have 3 and only 3 values for each saiyan.

Answer (score 0):

Ignoring why this may not be a good idea, and assuming that, in the old tables, for every instance of a row in Table1, there will be up to three rows in Table2 each with `Identifier` equal to 1, 2, or 3, you can do this with scalar subqueries:

```
INSERT INTO NewTable2 (Identifier, ID, value1, value2, value3)
SELECT 1, ID,
    (SELECT Value FROM NewTable2 AS T1 WHERE T1.ID=NT2.ID AND Identifier=1),
    (SELECT Value FROM NewTable2 AS T2 WHERE T2.ID=NT2.ID AND Identifier=2),
    (SELECT Value FROM NewTable2 AS T3 WHERE T3.ID=NT2.ID AND Identifier=3)
FROM OldTable2 AS NT2
GROUP BY ID;
```

There are other ways to crack this nut, such as joining NewTable2 to itself in the FROM of the SELECT.  But this shows what's going on and should execute the same way.

Answer (score 0):

Your new base is not a good idea, even if you you'll always have 3 value.

Anyway, here is the query :

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/32800b/1)

**MySQL 5.6 Schema Setup**:

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT SD.ID, t1.Value, t2.Value, t3.Value
FROM SaiyanDistribution SD
INNER JOIN (
        SELECT `ID`, `Value`
        FROM SaiyanDistributionValues
        WHERE `Identifier` IN (
            SELECT MIN(`Identifier`)
            FROM SaiyanDistributionValues
            GROUP BY  ID
        )
    ) t1
    ON t1.ID = SD.ID
INNER JOIN (
        SELECT `ID`, `Value`
        FROM SaiyanDistributionValues
        WHERE `Identifier` NOT IN (
            SELECT MIN(`Identifier`)
            FROM SaiyanDistributionValues
            GROUP BY  ID
            UNION
            SELECT MAX(`Identifier`)
            FROM SaiyanDistributionValues
            GROUP BY  ID
        )
    ) t2
    ON t2.ID = SD.ID
INNER JOIN (
        SELECT `ID`, `Value`
        FROM SaiyanDistributionValues
        WHERE `Identifier` IN (
            SELECT MAX(`Identifier`)
            FROM SaiyanDistributionValues
            GROUP BY  ID
        )
    ) t3
    ON t3.ID = SD.ID
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/32800b/1/0)**:

```
| ID |       Value |           Value |           Value |
|----|-------------|-----------------|-----------------|
|  1 | SuperSaiyan |    SuperSaiyan2 | SuperSaiyanBlue |
|  2 | SuperSaiyan | SuperSaiyanBlue |  SuperSaiyanRed |
```